# How can I merge multiple char arrays including the null chars they might contain?

Tags: c++, sockets, char

I am trying to implement an application network protocol with the following structure:

```
|First 2 bytes is the command|next 4 bytes is the payload length|and then the payload|
```

Command is a char[2] and payload length is a char[4].

I am using the following function to convert the payload length (int) to a 4 bytes array. If the payload length is less than 256 bytes, the first 3 bytes of the array that holds this value are null and only the last one contains the value.

```
void intToBytes(int value, char *buffer)
{
    buffer[0] = (value >> 24) & 0xff;
    buffer[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xff;
    buffer[2] = (value >> 8)  & 0xff;
    buffer[3] = value & 0xff;
 }
```

How can I merge the command char[2], the payload length char[4] and the payload char[any] into a new char array?

I tried:

```
strcpy(msg,command);
strcat(msg,payloadlength);
strcat(msg,payload);
```

but the msg char array contains only the command and the payload and ignores the payloadlength bytes. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: C or C++? Answers will be very different.

Comment: @hyde: The project is in C++

Comment: Ok, removed C tag. Also note, unless you were using `using namespace std`, you should use `std::strcpy` for functions from `#include <cstring>`. Leavning `std::` out will mostly work, but is not guaranteed by C++ standard.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use C-style string functions, they're for C-style strings. This is arbitrary binary data and you should use functions appropriate for arbitrary binary data. Perhaps `std::vector <unsigned char>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use strings functions to manipulate binary data.
If you use c, then you should use `memcpy()` function.
If you use c++, then the best thing is std::vector.

Comment: In C++ it would also be possible to use `std::string` for a byte array, as it doesn't care about NUL chars itself, but I think `std::vector` is more common.